# .htaccess Problems with Rewriting Rules

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, apache2

I was playing around with .htaccess a bit today because I wanted to try creating flat-links. My code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^$ router.php?path=home [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ router.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ router.php?path=$1&target=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My two problems now are, that the first rule doesnt apply to example.com/ and i get just a Forbidden error and that the rules don't change the link https://example.com/home to https://example.com/router.php?path=home but that the QUERY_STRING is "path=router&path=home".  All i do in my router.php is printing out the $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]....

Looked in the apache2.conf, according to several tutorials its set up correctly, gave chatgpt a try, failed, tried to add +SymLinksIfOwnerMatched, didnt do a thing...

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Well well... it seems like rule 1 and 2 apply as well as rule 1 and 3 based on which link is give, but the rewrite happens twice. any idea, how to rewrite the first rule to make it work?

Comment: Try using the `[END]` flag instead of the `[L]` flag.